# Laravel allowing null dates on Model::create() but not Model->update()

Tags: mysql, laravel, datetime, laravel-5, nullable

I have setup my Laravel migration to allow `nullable` dates for my StartTime and EndTime entries as such:

```
$table->dateTime( 'StartTime' )->nullable();
$table->dateTime( 'EndTime' )->nullable();
```

When I create a new entry through eloquent, it allows me to insert `null` values into my database successfully:

```
try {

    // Create the new Campaign record
    $campaign = Campaign::create( $request->all() );

}


+----+-------+--------+-----------+---------+---------------------+
| Id | Name  | Active | StartTime | EndTime | created_at          |
+----+-------+--------+-----------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 | Test2 |      0 | NULL      | NULL    | 2020-07-02 22:01:22 |
+----+-------+--------+-----------+---------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, when I later try and update my record using eloquent and still passing a `null` value for StartTime, it throws an error:

```
try {

    // Get a reference to the campaign
    $campaign = Campaign::find( $id );
            
    // Update the campaign
    $campaign->update( $request->all() );

}


(22007) SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: 'null' for column 'StartTime' at row 1
```

In the case of the `create` method, I am not passing in a StartTime value at all, but in the case of the `update` method, I am simply passing back the `null` value that Laravel returns as part of the model. So in other words, I haven't altered the value of StartTime at all, I've simply just passed `$campaign` back to Laravel for the update.

So it seems that Laravel is assigning the `nullable()` upon insert of a new entry into the database, but will not allow me to pass a `null` value back for the update.

Am I missing something here?  I can't seem to find a solution to this anywhere.

**UPDATE**

Okay, so further investigation seems like my problem is stemming from the AngularJS `$http` POST request. For troubleshooting purposes, I added code to my Laravel controller to alter the StartTime to `null`:

```
if( $request->StartTime === 'null' ) {

   $request['StartTime'] = null;

}
```

And that worked. So it looks like Angular is passing the `null` value back in the request as `'null'`

Comment: Show the code you're using to update your record. The error message suggests a string `'null'` vs `null`, but since you didn't post any code, that's simply a guess.

Answer (score 0):

> **Laravel 5.3** was updated to use MySQL "strict" mode by default, which includes the `NO_ZERO_DATE` mode.

The issue is that your existing data was allowed to have '0000-00-00 00:00:00' as a datetime value. But, now your connection is using a sql mode that does not allow that value (`NO_ZERO_DATE`).

However, the quick option is to just disable "strict" mode on your database connection. Open your `config/database.php` file, and make sure your database connection shows `'strict' => false`.

Or, create migration like this :

```
$table->datetime('StartTime')->nullable($value = true);
```

Or,

```
$table->datetime('StartTime')->default(null);
```

Comment: I tried changing the `strict` mode to `false` and that allowed it, however, it wrote the entries into my database as '0000-00-00 00:00:00' instead of `null`.  I don't understand how it allows the null on a create method but not the update.

Comment: This is mostly a MySql issue, as zero dates are disabled for newer versions of MySql. In addition, the NO_ZERO_DATE mode was deprecated (see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date). To get around this, you could change all zero dates in your database to the unix epoch time 1970-01-01 00:00:00 (which is what I had to do with mine after upgrading MySql).